# Vue.js Webpack template head tag

Tags: webpack, vue.js

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/

Using vue cli - generating html file... keep getting a head tag which doesn't exist in my template.

---

More detail:

I have an existing application - written in hapi.js. It serves up rendered html pages. Nunjunks is used for templating.

I have a Vue SPA / widget (built using view cli, and vue webpack) that must sit within the Nunjunks rendered html.

In my nunjunks template, I have a partial `{% include 'vueapps/paintpicker.html' %}`

I have set `config/index.js` to output the file as `paintpicker.html`into the vueapps directory.

my index.html file (from which paintpicker.html is generated) looks like this:

```
{% extends 'layout/web-layout.html' %}
{% block main %}
     <div id="app"></div>
{% endblock %}
```

However... once built, my paintpicker.html file looks like this (I've added new lines to make it easier to read).

```
<head>
<link href=/static/css/app.1de2d621551be454289c9d7cf89d0ded.css rel=stylesheet>
</head>
{% extends 'layout/web-layout.html' %} 
{% block main %}
<div id=app></div>
{% endblock %}
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js></script><script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.158e5ebf7c414a428726.js></script>
<script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.99b16fc5705b655dd61b.js></script>
```

I'm receiving a `<head>` tag - and I don't know how I can get rid of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... under the hood, html-webpack is being used. I went into /build/webpack.prod.conf.js, and set inject to false.

Then, taking variables from this template -

https://github.com/jaketrent/html-webpack-template/blob/86f285d5c790a6c15263f5cc50fd666d51f974fd/index.html

I was able to insert them into my template. The result now renders as required.

https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin

See the section on webpack.config.js for info.