# Vue CLI "index.html" content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli-3

whenever i run `npm run build` it generates an dist folder with my app everything good but..

My Problem:

When i open my `index.html` there are`<!DOCTYPE>, <head>, <body>` tags but in my case i just need the `<div id="app">` with the CSS and JS files.

Question:

Is it possible to remove the tags that i dont need to be generated like in my case `<!DOCTYPE>, <body>, <head>`?

Whenever i run `npm run build` it should look like this when i open `index.html`:

```
<link href=/testing/path/css/app.6878f4f8.css rel=preload as=style>
<link href=/testing/path/js/app.457dc9d3.js rel=preload as=script>
<link href=/testing/path/js/chunk-vendors.a0cfb1f1.js rel=preload as=script>
<link href=/testing/path/css/app.6878f4f8.css rel=stylesheet>
 <div id=app>
 </div>
<script src=/testing/path/js/chunk-vendors.a0cfb1f1.js></script>
<script src=/testing/path/js/app.457dc9d3.js></script>
```

Otherwise i need to open the file and remove it manually

Comment: Why do you need that? I don't get it, but you could just write a script for that to delete those lines and run it after build with postbuild.

Comment: @Natixco i am building an app on an existing website. its build with magento and it has an template that already has `body, head, DOCTYPE` tags

Comment: the hint is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50180203/vue-js-webpack-template-head-tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vue CLI generated projects use `public/index.html` as a template, which contains the headers and tags you'd like to avoid. The only element there required for Vue is `<div id="app"></div>`, so you could remove everything but that from `public/index.html`.

Note that the [`preload`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#preload), [`prefetch`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#prefetch), and CSS plugins (enabled by default) will insert a `<head>`. You can disable the `preload` and `prefetch` plugins with this config:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
    config.plugins.delete('preload')
  }
}
```

The final output would be similar to this:

```html
<head><link href=/css/app.e2713bb0.css rel=stylesheet></head>
<div id=app></div>
<script src=/js/chunk-vendors.327f60f7.js></script>
<script src=/js/app.fb8740dd.js></script>
```